# Shopware6: how to delete all demo data

Tags: shopware

I've tried to find answer, but without any result.
Some commands of `bin/console` and `./psh.phar` are without description, so it is difficult to understand their purposes.

Is there a command to delete all demo data from database in Shopware 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to execute `./psh.phar init`.
As stated in the description, it

> Installs database and dependencies with default data set

After that you should have a clean database with default data, but without demo data. Note that this will reset your complete data. There is no command to only delete demo data.

Comment: Should be `./psh.phar`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is *incomplete*, at least if you use docker.

The command kills not only the data in the database, it also removes all docker dependencies for the administration.

I don't no, if this behavior are correct or a bug,but it's not intuitive!

To rebuild the dependencies, you have to execute `./psh.phar administration:init`